# Django redirect is not redirecting

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm new to Django and instead of using Django forms ,I'm using bootrap forms with user model that I have created I have to check the login details before giving access to the user dashboard .

Here's the code

```
def login (request):
   if request.method=="POST":
      email=request.POST.get('email')
      password=request.POST.get('password')
      user=authenticate (request,email=email, password=password)
      if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        return redirect ('/dashboard')

      else:
        context="Provide Valid Credentials"
        return render(request."login.html",context)
```

print(user) gives None value even though data is present in the user model

**URLs.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from start_app.views import login

urlpatterns =[
path('login/',login)
path('dashboard/', dashboard)
]
```

**login.html**

```
<form  method="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
      <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

It's not redirecting me to the dashboard .

**plz ignore the indentation as I'm unable to do it here**

Any suggestions will be appreciated?

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation of your code block?

Comment: Please enclose the `urls.py` file and mention what is the output. Are you redirecting to another page?

Comment: Yes it's not getting redirected

Comment: @Anonymous What does `print(email, password)` give you? Show the template for this form too.

Comment: template file for form is above
and print(email, password) is printing None

Comment: I've corrected everything and now it's working but how should I do using authenticate function ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your login.html.
You should include the name attribute in your form fields.  That’s what Django tries to grab when you call `request.POST.get()`.
So you should edit your html code to something like this.

```
<form  method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password>
  <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox mb-3">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
  </label>
</div>
<button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

And then in your urls.py try and include the name argument.

In your urls.py file you can do something like this.

```
path('dashboard/', dashboard, name="dashboard")
path("login/", login, name="login")
```

Also edit your views.py file.
Don't use `request.POST.get()` but rather `request.POST['attribute name']`

Comment: Still happening the same thing look I have changed

Comment: Did you import views?  If you can please share the whole urls.py including imports

Comment: Try the above change.

Comment: If I access directly from the database then it's possible but using authenticate the user is getting 'None' value